# batch file variable doesn't work inside if statement, even with delayed expansion?

Tags: batch-file

I'm writing a batch file that will modify an input file but only if the filename contains `-source`.

This works:

```
@echo off
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set fn=%1
echo Checking %fn%...
set outfile=%fn:-source=%
if not x%fn:-source=%==x%fn% (
    echo Output to %outfile%
)
```

but this does not:

```
@echo off
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set fn=%1
echo Checking %fn%...
if not x%fn:-source=%==x%fn% (
    set outfile=%fn:-source=%
    echo Output to %outfile%
)
```

In the second case, it simply outputs "Output to" with no file name.  How can I fix this?

Comment: The second version should be, `echo Output to !outfile!`

Comment: oh, so you still set it with % but you reference it with !.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your second script again, with my answer from my comment and some additional improvements with regard double quoting.

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~1"=="" Exit/B
Set "fn=%~1"
Echo Checking %fn%...
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If Not "x%fn:-source=%"=="x%fn%" (
    Set "outfile=%fn:-source=%"
    Echo Output to !outfile!
)
```

As an additional note, if `"x%fn:-source=%"` does equal `"x%fn%"` there is no need to use the `If`, *(making a substitution which doesn't alter the value is harmless)*.

```bat
@Echo Off
If "%~1"=="" Exit/B
Set "fn=%~1"
Echo Checking %fn%...
Set "outfile=%fn:-source=%"
Echo Output to %outfile%
```

Comment: "making a substitution which doesn't alter the value is harmless" Obviously I removed some code that was irrelevant to the question.  But thanks for the answer.